# How to `compute` outer file?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In main.js:

```
import player from './package/Player';

Vue.use(player);
...
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  player,
```

and player.js:

```
    export default function (Vue) {
  let isPlaying = true;

  Vue.player = {
    changePlaying(){
      let before = isPlaying;
      isPlaying = !isPlaying;
      let after = isPlaying;

      console.log(before, after);
    },
    getPlaying(){
      return isPlaying;
    }
  };
  Object.defineProperties(Vue.prototype, {
    $player:{
      get: () => {
        return Vue.player;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

and in App:

```
 computed:{
      player(){
          return this.$player.getPlaying();
      }
  },
```

That works good, but when parametr in player.js is changing, in app.vue it is not changing. How to solve that problem?
For example when i click on button in app.vue, in console i can see this:
true false
false true
true false
etc..

So, it means that info is changing, but how to check it?

Also i tried to do that with vuex, but there we can only store information, but i need to transform it, so vuex is not goo idea.

So, there is an question:
how to check some info in outer file?

Answer (score 0):

One simple way around this is to use a `Vue` instance for your `isPlaying` variable to make it reactive:

```
let isPlaying = new Vue({
  data: {
    status: true
  }
});
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/289h9a88/